# How does NATS / JetStream "remember" subscribers?

Tags: python, nats.io, nats-streaming-server, nats-jetstream

I'm doing my first steps with NATS and see behavior I cannot make sense of, even after reading the docs quite carefully. I have a local NATS server (2.6.5) running. It was started with

```
./nats-server -js
```

I generate some messages with the following code:

```
async def main():
    nc = await nats.connect()
    js = nc.jetstream()

    await js.delete_stream(name="hello")
    await js.add_stream(
        name="hello",
        subjects=["hello"],
    )
    for i in range(0, 10):
        await js.publish("hello", f"hello world: {i}".encode())
    await nc.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If I run the code and execute `./nats stream ls` I see 10 messages. Everything fine so far. Next I run my consumer:

```
async def main():
    nc = await nats.connect()
    js = nc.jetstream()
    sub = await js.pull_subscribe("hello", "hello")

    msg_count = 0
    while msg_count < 10:
        for msg in await sub.fetch(1):
            print("Received:", msg.data)
            msg_count = msg_count + 1

            # Try nack'ing every third message
            if msg_count % 3 == 0:
                await msg.nak()
            else:
                await msg.ack()

    await nc.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The output shows:

```
Received: b'hello world: 0'
Received: b'hello world: 1'
Received: b'hello world: 2'
Received: b'hello world: 2'
Received: b'hello world: 3'
Received: b'hello world: 4'
Received: b'hello world: 4'
Received: b'hello world: 5'
Received: b'hello world: 6'
Received: b'hello world: 6'
```

That makes sense: I pull 10 messages. Every third message is "naked", so it is retrieved again by the next call. If I start the script again the output is:

```
Received: b'hello world: 7'
Received: b'hello world: 8'
Received: b'hello world: 9'
Received: b'hello world: 9'
```

And after a few seconds I get a time out. Obviously NATS somehow remembers my script and continues with delivering messages. But I don't get how this happens!? Is there a "global" cursor in the stream? But in that case multiple clients would interfere, which does not make sense to me. So I assume that NATS somehow remembers my client. How? And how would I tell NATS that I want to restart? I would also appreciate a pointer to the docs that I obviously missed!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a pull subscription, the jetstream client API also creates a *durable* consumer with matching consumer options, in this case the stream name and a [durable name](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream/consumers#durable-name) (the second argument).

```
sub = await js.pull_subscribe("hello", "hello")
```

> A durable consumer is intended to be long-lived and the server will
> keep track of where the consumer is in the stream. So if the consumer
> stops then restarts, it will automatically restart where it left off
> and the configuration used to initialize the consumer will be
> remembered. A durable consumer is required when making a pull
> subscription and is optional when making a push subscription.

Source: https://nats.io/blog/jetstream-java-client-03-consume/#durable-vs-ephemeral